# Asynchronous client socket c#. How can i wait in loop for informations from the server without blocking the operation of the program?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, asynchronous, tcpclient

I created class to communicate with TCP server like this:

```
public class Tcp_client_server_communication
{
    private static TcpClient client;
    private static String response = String.Empty;

    public void Initialize(string ip, int port)
    {
        client = new TcpClient(ip, port);

    }
    public string BeginRead()
    {
        var buffer = new byte[16];
        var ns = client.GetStream();
        ns.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, EndRead, buffer);
     
    }

    public void EndRead(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var buffer = (byte[])result.AsyncState;
        var ns = client.GetStream();
        var bytesAvalible = ns.EndRead(result);

        MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
        BeginRead();

    }
}
```

To call these methods I use:

```
.Initialize();
.BeginRead();
```

Its works fine but I want to show the every message from the server in a multi-line `TextBox` not in a `MessageBox`.

How can I do this?

Comment: First mistake is ignoring `bytesAvailable`, which tells you how much of `buffer` is valid. Second mistake is to assume "message". TCP is an *endless stream of bytes*, not messages. `Write` and `Read` aren't "paired up" 1-1. at the two ends.

Comment: so your question has basically nothing to do with tcpclient or stream reading, but with writing stuff to a multiline Textbox from a different thread. So these are the 2 Things you should research: 1) "C# write multiple strings to multiline textbox" and 2) "C# write text to control from different thread", you can just copy paste these search queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could create a List object to hold all the messages passed, then set a Timer to check every so often if the list has been added to.  Remove what you've read every tick from the list after adding the message to the textbox.

This project is a little more complicated then that but here's one of my old projects I worked on in middle school as an example : https://github.com/Taloreal/Server-Essentials